# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'

Tags: element, declaration

I have below code in my config.xml file

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation=
"    http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd

    <beans:oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="SampleTestmapper"
            contextPath="com.sample.base.Testing001"/>
```

Above code gives me error saying that The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'oxm:jaxb2-marshaller'.

I have declared correct version of oxm which is 3.1.xsd in compliance with my spring version. And I also have required jar file in class path.Any idea why I am still getting error ?

Note: in my pom.xml this is how I added dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

```xml
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="SampleTestmapper"
            contextPath="com.sample.base.Testing001"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).